# (content) Propagation + website in multiple languages

Tags: craft3, plugin-neo

Currently we're developing a craft multi-site that has 3 languages (nl, fr, en). It's an upgrade (new style, removing junk, ..) from another cms so the content has to be inputted manually.

We've used a **NEO block** with different options for the layouting the content.
Now because 80% of the content is the same for the 3 languages, the **propagation method** for this block was set to **"Save blocks to all sites the owner element is saved in"**.

Almost all of the content has been added, except for the last 20% which differs in some blocks not existing in certain languages.

Now we wanted to change the propagation method, but this deletes all the blocks in the others languages when we save an entry.

Is there a way to change the method without overwriting our data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone has a better answer than me, but I’ve been in the same situation recently and the way I eventually did it was to output the field for each page in Json using element api, then create a new field that does allow different blocks per locale/site and re-import the content back into that field per locale using feed me.

I left both fields on the control panel for a period of time so the client could check everything was correct, then moved the templates over to use the new field.